# Is there any free unlimited album artwork search API service?

Tags: search-engine, artwork

Google's custom search API has a limitation up to 100 queries per day. That is far less than what I expected. I want to add that artwork-search function to my app. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about [Discogs](http://www.discogs.com/help/forums/topic/167057), or [Amazon](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/06/24/getting-album-art-using-amazon-web-services/) or seeing what [Cover Fetcher](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/amaroK-Scripts/Cover-Fetcher-39314.shtml) does?

Comment: discogs seems promising, thanks.

Comment: Last I read the Amazon Terms of Service, you could only use their album art in the context of selling albums with their affiliate program.

Comment: As of earlier this year, Discogs is no longer unlimited: http://www.onemusicapi.com/blog/2014/08/13/app-developers-think-twice-adopting-discogs-api/ . Furthermore, @Brad is correct.

Comment: Also try [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) and [Itunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Answer (score 9):

Musicbrainz and the Internet Archive offer the [Cover Art Archive](http://coverartarchive.org/) but you do need to request using the album's [MBID](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MBID).

Answer (score 7):

Last.FM provides an API for getting art but you can't actually use it in publicly distributed applications. They said that the recording companies own the art and they aren't licensed to distribute it. Huh? Why the API then? I don't get it.

Comment: exactly my point ..... I don't get this stupidity..

Comment: is this possible, instead of using our own key we ask the users to provide their key ....

Answer (score 2):

Last FM's [album.getInfo](http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.getInfo) API call offers images in four different sizes and can be searched using names or [musicbrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) IDs.  Output can be XML/JSON/JSONP.

Comment: Last fm images are  not for public use ...

Answer (score 2):

Last.fm isn't completely free and unlimited
"Last.fm reserves the right to share in revenue generated from your use of Last.fm Data in future on terms to be negotiated in good faith between Last.fm and You."

Discovered the FreeCover website API a few minutes ago searching for the same thing:
http://www.freecovers.net/api/

For the record, ROVi seems loaded (they source Apple):
http://developer.rovicorp.com/

...but same as every good service on the internet: if you want good (meaning reliable) service, you'll have to pay eventually ;)

Comment: If you make good revenue out of their API, isn't that obvious that you might have to share a bit of this revenue with them? #justsaying

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had write it on the last line of my answer.
Did you understand otherwise ? Please correct me if so !

Comment: Last fm images are not for public use  or are they ??I contacted them and they said no... @RemiGrumeau

Comment: Then this API is just for their own apps use. For internal scalibility sake.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the Cover Art Archive the only other approachably "free" and unlimited resource is Wikipedia: http://www.onemusicapi.com/blog/2014/09/10/querying-wikipedia-album-artwork/

You can use DBpedia to search for the album, then use the Wikimedia APIs to actually download the image.