# Getting album covers online

Tags: database, ftp

Is there some database of album covers that is commonly used? The best I could find is:
http://www.albumartexchange.com/

What are some specific topics I should be familiar with in order to query for a specific cover and then download it, especially if I am looking for cross platform functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543574/is-there-any-free-unlimited-album-artwork-search-api-service)

Cover Fetcher, as mentioned in the answers there, uses AudioScrobbler/LastFM. I used it a few months ago and the request was something like

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?
      method=album.getinfo
     &api_key=XXXXXXXX
     &album=YYYYYY
     &artist=ZZZZZZ
```

(Response is XML with the links in there somewhere)

I just looked at the [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/coverfetcher/files/), and they still use the same URL. [Here](https://gist.github.com/felipeochoa/5439424) is a Gist with the code I used (Python3) I've X'ed out the API Key, but obeythepenguin's source has it in there.